# Is it true that push notifications are not received unless the app is opened manually?

Tags: push-notification

Is it true that push notifications are not received on a device unless the app is opened manually after the installation?

I have published an app but the user is not getting push notification before they open the app manually after installation.

If it is not true then please let me know what could be the possible issue?

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,

Riz

Answer (score 0):

For the user to start receiving post-notifications they need to open the app and allow the notifications to be sent. Post-notifications won't be sent unless the user has allowed them.